# Classes not maintained with Bootstrap .popover

Tags: jquery, class, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using Twitter Bootstrap popover for adding labels.

In the popover I load the list of labels with html selector, when a label is click I add a class. The problem is when I close the popover and want to open it for the second time, the classes that are set are not visible again.

Here is my JS:

```
    var isVisible = false;
    var clickedAway = false;

    $('.btn-label-popover').popover({
            animation: true,
            placement: 'top',
            title: 'Selecteer labels',
            content: $('.controls .popover-content').html(),
            trigger: 'manual'
        }).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(isVisible & clickedAway){
                $('.btn-label-popover').popover('hide');
                isVisible = clickedAway = false;
            } else {
                $(this).popover('show');
                clickedAway = false;
                isVisible = true;
            }
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.popover-content span', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        var identifier = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        $('.'+identifier+' span').toggleClass('label-inverse');
        $('.'+identifier+' span').toggleClass('label-reminder');
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
      if(isVisible & clickedAway)
      {
        $('.btn-label-popover').popover('hide');
        isVisible = clickedAway = false;
      }
      else
      {
        clickedAway = true;
      }
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            if(isVisible & clickedAway)
            {
                $('.btn-label-popover').popover('hide');
                isVisible = clickedAway = false;
            } else {
                clickedAway = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there any way to get the HTML with the added classes? Big thanks!

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are losing your classes is because Twitter bootstrap removes the popover from the DOM when its hidden. You will need to store the id/class for each of the changed popovers in an array and use that to re-add the necessary classes. For example:

```
var identifiers = [];

$('.btn-label-popover').popover({
        // your options
    }).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(isVisible & clickedAway){
            $('.btn-label-popover').popover('hide');
            isVisible = clickedAway = false;
        } else {
            $(this).popover('show');

            // Loop through changed popovers
            for(i=0; i<identifiers.length, i++){
                $('.'+identifiers[i]+' span').toggleClass('label-inverse');
                $('.'+identifier[i]+' span').toggleClass('label-reminder');
            }
            clickedAway = false;
            isVisible = true;
        }
});

$('body').on('click', '.popover-content span', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var identifier = $(this).parent().attr('class');

    // Add to an array
    identifiers.push(identifier);

    $('.'+identifier+' span').toggleClass('label-inverse');
    $('.'+identifier+' span').toggleClass('label-reminder');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not the case. The classes aren't deleted when clicking on the body. Only toggled when clicking on the label itself, as it supposed to do. The problem is that when I toggle some classes, then close the popover. After that when opening the popover again all the selected labels (classes) are gone.

Comment: Ah apologies @ChrisKoster I had breezed over your use of `on` with a selector. I'll take another look.

Comment: I've added a revised solution mate.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Steve! Working now. I thought the popover was just shown and hidden because I didn't use destroy. Well, again thank you.